# Create threads in multiprocessing to process and write images to local

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, tiff

I have huge list of images which I want to write to local , I applied multithreading and still it is slow.so I want to create multiple processes using multiprocessing package and then create multiple threads in each process.

Sharing an example code which may not be exactly what i'm doing.

```
def write_data(img_name, data):
    with open('/users/img_name.png') as f:
        f.write(data)

def process_data(image_dict):
    for img_name, data in image_dict.items():
        threads = []
        #create threads to and call write_data() with arrguments
        t1 = Threading.thread(target=write(), args=[img_name, data])
        t1.start()

  def main(image_dict):
   #huge dict with key as image name and value as byte_arr
   image_dict={"img_1":[[0,0,0]]..........}
   #consider there are 1000 imgs and 4 processes created and each process 
   #will pick 250 images
   for _ in range(4):
       #pass 0 to 250 imgs to process 1 and 251 to 500 to process2
       #using multprocessing package
       p1 = Process(target=process_data args=[])
```

Here args accepting numeric value and not accepting dictionary python, how to make dict accessible to all the processes and share the chunk of 250 images to each process to make write faster.Please help.